# Aligning metagenomic reads (OTU representatives) to my phylogenetic tree ~AND~ evaluating how multiple samples align

Tags: phylogeny

So...

I am working with amino acid sequences.

I got a fasta file containing reference sequences and a txt file giving the categorization (domain, subdomain, nickname etc etc etc.) for each sequence. First thing, I need to construct a tree with these sequences to check that they group according to the categories they belong to. Example: sequences belonging to domain A group together, sequences belonging to subdomain A1 group together and so on.

Then... I got a fasta file containing OTU representatives derived from metagenomic reads AND a OTU count table declaring how many of each of these representatives are present in each one of my 20 samples. I need to align these OTU sequences to the previously constructed tree ~AND~ consider the per-sample count, to check the categories each sample is enriched for.

What softwares should I use?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

We used MAFFT for alignment and [Fasttree](http://www.microbesonline.org/fasttree/) to build phylogenetic trees, but there are many other options.

We used [pplacer](https://github.com/matsen/pplacer) to add short aminoacid sequences derived from metagenomic reads to a tree. Not sure about the abundance part, but you could get started from there